# HTML inside of external jQuery function not working

Tags: jquery, html, href

I have an external javascript file that loads HTML within a div on my html page:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('img#madhere').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $('#extras').html('<ul class="animated flash"><li class="drop"><a id="infobutton" class="scroll" href="#bottomcontent"></a><div class="dropdownContain"><div class="dropOut"><ul><li><a id="show_madhere_info" href="">Info</a></li><li><a id="show_madhere_credits" href="">Credits</a></li><li><a id="show_madhere_trivia" href="">Trivia</a></li><li><a class="twits" href="https://twitter.com/share?text=Check%20out%20%22Were%20All%20Mad%20Here%22%20on%20Jick%20Pictures&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jickpictures.com" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li><li><a class="facebooker" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=19884028963&ref=share_popup&link=http%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2F58261368&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2F58261368%3Fclose" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li><li><a class="tuber" href="http://youtu.be/TFht5BGvoLU" target="_blank">YouTube</a></li><li><a class="vimeos" href="https://vimeo.com/58261368" target="_blank">Vimeo</a></li><li><a class="reddits" href="http://www.reddit.com/submit" onclick="window.location = "http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location); return false" target="_blank">Reddit</a></li></ul></div></div></li></ul>');  
  });
});
```

It loads up just fine with the exception of my links working. The links require yet ANOTHER external javascript file with a new function when the links are clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#show_madhere_info").click(function() {
            $("div#modal").addClass("show");
```

My problem is that the jquery function for showing "show_madhere_info" div will not work. Instead it reverts to the "href" link which just makes the page reload.

```
<a id="show_madhere_info" href="">Info</a>
```

It's like it can't recognize the div from my HTML inside of another jquery function. Does that make sense? What can I do here to make the links work after the content loads from the previous jQuery function?

Comment: Perhaps I will just have to show you because it's hard to explain. [PREVIEW](http:///www.jickpictures.com/preview). Hover over "what's up" then click "info". It works on initial page load. Then click on "Were all mad here" movie at the bottom left. The "what's up" button will reload with that information in the 1st code I provided. However when you click "info" again, it does not recognize the ID to the link again to the 2nd code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically inserted elements require the use of the .on() function and won't work using the standard .click() method.

Try using this:

```
$(document).on('click', $("#show_madhere_info"), function(e) {

  e.preventDefault(); //stop the usual href action      
  ...

}
```

Also make sure your using the latest version of jQuery 1.9.x

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps I will just have to show you because it's hard to explain. [PREVIEW](http:///www.jickpictures.com/preview). Hover over "what's up" then click "info". It works on initial page load. Then click on "Were all mad here" movie at the bottom left. The "what's up" button will reload with that information in the 1st code I provided. However when you click "info" again, it does not recognize the ID to the link again to the 2nd code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery >= 1.7, use event delegation for dynamically added content

```
$('#extras').on('click', '#show_madhere_info', function(e){
    $("div#modal").addClass("show");
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps I will just have to show you. [PREVIEW](http:///www.jickpictures.com/preview). Hover over "what's up" then click "info". It works on initial page load. Then click on "Were all mad here" movie at the bottom left. The "what's up" button will reload with that information in the 1st code I provided. However when you click "info" again, it does not recognize the ID to the link again to the 2nd code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

In html you can use:

```
<a id="show_madhere_info" href="javascript:void(0);">Info</a>
```

In the code you can try:

```
$(document).on("click", "#show_madhere_info", function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();
  //do what you want
}
```

Comment: No dice, but thanks for your input though. Please look at my comment above to see what I am talking about. It's hard to explain.